# Quering a stored procedure in ORACLE using fitnesse / dbfit

Tags: oracle, fitnesse, dbfit

How to specify a query that uses a stored procedure within a package?
For example this query fails with a message:

```
!|Query|SELECT * FROM TABLE (pckg.GetData('param1'))|
|field1|
|value1|

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentException: Column 'ugp_udf_name' does not belong to table Table.
   at System.Data.DataRow.GetDataColumn(String columnName)
   at System.Data.DataRow.get_Item(String columnName)
   at fitSharp.Machine.Engine.InvokeDataRow`2.Invoke(TypedValue instance, MemberName memberName, Tree`1 parameters)
...(the rest of the stack trace)
```

Answer (score 0):

DbFit rocks...

```
!|Query|SELECT pckg.GetData('param1') field1 from dual|
|field1|
|value1|
```

Comment: I fixed the typo in the original question's sql statement. It should work as is. For my case using dual doesn't work - throws "Unsupported Oracle data type USERDEFINED encountered" error, but it seems to be due to type/s of fields that are being returning, so could work for other cases.

Comment: yes, user-defined types are not supported in dbfit. You'd have to select the object attributes directly.